# Memory Leak while Stopping Tomcat Server 9 (War File Grails)

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have generated the WAR file using grails WAR and deployed this WAR file on tomcat server.
I have default scheduler from grails and custom scheduler using Quartz in java Quartz.properties file is defined in resource.
Well it is working fine , but when I shutdown the server It shows some issue in closing thread.

**I have grails ScheduleJob which runs every minute, and this execute a Java Class and this java class reads database and based on the info schedule new job using quartz. Quartz Scheduler keeps scheduling new Job, there is no way to shutdown the Quartz Scheduler , grailsScheduler (Trigger) -> JavaClass (Quartz Scheuler) . Grails scheduler is continuously running and trigger the Java class which uses the Quartz Scheduler, When I shutdown the tomcat, Quartz Thread is still active, I have no way to Call the Quartz Scheduler shutdown method.
we can call the Quartz Scheduler shutdown method only when, user shutdown the tomcat server, but don't know how?**

GrailsCode:

```
class ScheduleJob {     static triggers = {        simple repeatInterval: 100000 // execute job once in 1 minute     }      def execute() {                 new ScheduleIBJob().schedule()           } }
```

Portion of whole java code,

```
public static Scheduler scheduler = null;   public static Scheduler getSchedulerJobObject() throws SchedulerException {         if (scheduler == null) {            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();           scheduler.start();          }               return scheduler;   }
```

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=IB_Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=99199
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy=false
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=3
org.quartz.context.key.QuartzTopic=QuartzPorperties
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons=true
org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.jndiURL=java:comp/env/jdbc/db
```

this is Error

```
04-Jun-2021 14:14:20.758 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Jun-2021 14:14:20.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [288,864] milliseconds
04-Jun-2021 14:14:35.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
04-Jun-2021 14:14:35.665 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.111 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.807 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Scheduler-2.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [IB_Scheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.808 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Scheduler-2.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [IB_Scheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.812 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Scheduler-2.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [IB_Scheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.814 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Scheduler-2.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [IB_Scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:410)
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.866 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Jun-2021 14:14:36.873 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: Looks like you don't shutdown the scheduler when the application stops, check the [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/cookbook/ShutdownScheduler.html) on how to do it.

Comment: Yes you are right, just wondering how to do it, I'm shutting down the tomcat server shutdown.sh and Scheduler shutdown code code is in WAR file.

Comment: How do you start your scheduler? For each init hook like [`Servlet#init`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servlet#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-) there is a destroy hook like `Servlet#destroy`.

Comment: Can you add this information to the question (edit the question) instead of a comment?

Comment: done , please check and let me know any other info you need

Comment: I am not a Grails expert, but since it is based on Spring, you should probably [inject a `quartzScheduler`](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.10/guide/services.html#dependencyInjectionServices) into your service instead of creating one yourself. This should solve the shutdown problem.

Comment: ``` org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown=true
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class=org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown=true
```
Is this work , I updated the properties but it is not working as mentioned.